# Logging RestClient in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rest-client

I'd like to debug the request my Rails app makes with [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client). The RestClient docs say:

> To enable logging you can
>
> set RestClient.log with a ruby Logger
>   or set an environment variable to avoid modifying the code (in this case you can use a file name, “stdout” or “stderr”):
>
> $ RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout path/to/my/program
>   Either produces logs like this:
>
> RestClient.get "http://some/resource"
>
> => 200 OK | text/html 250 bytes
>
> RestClient.put "http://some/resource", "payload"
>
> => 401 Unauthorized | application/xml 340 bytes
>
> Note that these logs are valid Ruby, so you can paste them into the restclient shell or a >script to replay your sequence of rest calls.

How do I do get these logs included in my Rails apps log folder?

Answer (score 15):

from: https://gist.github.com/jeremy/1383337

```
require 'restclient'

# RestClient logs using << which isn't supported by the Rails logger,
# so wrap it up with a little proxy object.
RestClient.log =
  Object.new.tap do |proxy|
    def proxy.<<(message)
      Rails.logger.info message
    end
  end
```

Comment: OR RestClient.log = $stdout

Comment: Add that into a file in `config/initializers/`

Answer (score 5):

Create a file in `config/initializers`:
RestClient.log = 'log/a_log_file.log'
Or just put last in console

https://github.com/adelevie/rest-client/commit/5a7ed325eaa091809141d3ef6e31087569614e9d

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, running on RestClient 1.8 and Rails 4.2.1:

`::RestClient.log = Rails.logger`

Comment: that can be added into `config/initializers/rest_client.rb` to globally enable

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem:

https://github.com/uswitch/rest-client-logger

It works out of the box just by adding "gem 'rest-client-logger'" to your Gemfile.

Answer (score -3):

may be so: RestClient.log = Rails.logger