# RestClient logging response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, rest-client

I can log simple request like below from the instructions post here

[Logging RestClient in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068496/logging-restclient-in-a-rails-app)

It logs the request but it does not log the response back from the call.

Is there anyway to tell RestClient to log the response as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it automagically, but you can just do it manually - usually this is only for dev / debugging anyway:

```
response = RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource'
puts response

// or break it up
puts response.code
puts response.headers
// and so on
```